# Is it possible to spoof a GPS satellite?

Tags: spoofing, geolocation, gps

If it is possible? Any devices that can be bought to do so.
If not, how are GPS satellites are designed to be spoof-free.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible — even easy. No, GPS satellites are not designed to be spoof-free.

GPS wasn't designed against satellite spoofing, probably because back then they didn't even dream of someone doing that. Even back in 2008, this wasn't something easy and affordable. From Wired: [Researchers Demonstrate How to Spoof GPS Devices](https://www.wired.com/2008/09/researchers-dup/):

> Researchers at Virginia Tech and Cornell University spent more than a
>   year building equipment that can transmit fake GPS signals capable of
>   fooling receivers.

Since then, this has become easier. All you need is a radio signal transmitter and some open-source software. See e.g. [GPS Spoofing w/ BladeRF](https://www.crazydanishhacker.com/gps-spoofing-bladerf-software-defined-radio-series-23/) from Crazy Danish Hacker.

Kaspersky's article on [Is it possible to guard against GPS attacks?](https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/gps-spoofing-protection/26837/) explains how this is not something that could be easily fixed:

> Although the problem has been known for some time, there is a major
>   obstacle to developing protection measures — the key equipment is in
>   space and will not be replaced right away. GPS satellites emit what
>   they emit, and no one can add standard protection tools, such as
>   encryption and certificates, to the signals. Security measures so far
>   have been more experimental in nature and not for large-scale
>   application.

Comment: Additionally, it is alleged that [Iran stole a US spy drone with GPS spoofing](https://www.wired.com/2011/12/iran-drone-hack-gps/). They (allegedly) jammed its standard communications channel and it failed over to flying home using GPS, which they spoofed, so it landed nice and neatly on a designated Iranian landing strip.

Comment: It currently does have anti-spoofing but it is military only (the US and US Allies) and not available in the civilian market.